# How to use global navigation across site

Tags: php

I'm creating a new site and I want to make it as easy as possible to update in the future. Part of this includes the links.

Currently, I have the global navigation included in my `header.php` file. I want to be able to access the links in one global location (`headers.php`). The goal is to use a variable within page content to display the current link location. i.e. `$news`, `$pressReleases` etc.

This will help me when it's time to update and modify links.

I'm thinking of using some type of include file that will get loaded in the `headers.php` file, something like a config file for navigation. i.e.

```
<?php
$events = "<li><a href="/media.php">Media & Events</a>";
$locations = <li><a href="/locations.php">locations</a>
?>
```

Is there a better way to do this? I'm not interested in using frameworks or a CMS for this project.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing HTML in variables, I'd use an array like:

```
$global_nav_menu = array(
    'Media & Events' => '/media.php',
    'Locations'      => '/locations.php'
);
```

In `headers.php`, you could have something like:

```
<ul id="global_nav_menu">
<?php foreach ($global_nav_menu as $label => $href): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $href; ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($label); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```